# Javascript date appears to be the wrong format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Please see the code below:

```
$.validator.addMethod("agerangevalidation", function (value, elements, params) {
    if (value) {
        var valDate = new Date(value);

        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(value); //line 7
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;
        }
        if (age < parseInt(params.minage) || age > parseInt(params.maxage))
        {
            //Validation failed
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

If the value passed is greater than the 12th of the month, then it is parsed into the wrong date.  Here is the datepicker code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,   
            changeYear: true,   
            yearRange: "-150:+0"  

        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I specify the format of the string in the Javascript code?

**Update**

Following on from an answer below I have installed Momentum.js and changed line 7 of the first segement of JavaScript to:

```
var birthDate = moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

I pass 16/08/1999 into the function and birthdate becomes 08/04/2000.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript Format is **MM/DD/YYYY** and your datepicker format is **DD/MM/YYYY**, and that's why you are getting this issue, i had the same issue before, i fixed it using dateFormat: **mm/dd/yyyyy**, or you can use **YYYY/MM/DD** which will also work.

you can try on your console these and maybe this will help you understand

```
new Date("2017/2/1");
//Wed Feb 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (note it detect yyyy/mm/dd)
new Date("1/2/2017");
//Mon Jan 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (note it detect mm/dd/yyyy)
new Date("13/2/2017");
//Invalid Date no month 13
```

**Update**

as per update, you want exact time parser based on format, 
for that you should use [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/guides/)
which will be something like this

```
moment(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format();
```

you can read more at [Momentjs Guide Page](https://momentjs.com/guides/)

Comment: There must be a way to change the JavaScript format?

Comment: check my edit, a way maybe if you used [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) which I think is not needed if you can easily provide the correct format

Comment: While Munzers answer is correct. There is a plugin called `MomentJS` [https://momentjs.com/] which will give you the functionality you wish. (including a Diff Function) to allow you to write less code. if you can add that to your project. It makes Dates MUCH easier

Comment: I think this is what you should be using 
`moment('16/08/1999', 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).format()`
I updated my answer, please consider upvote if I helped 
Thanks